# JAXB maven plugin not generating classes from .wsdl

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to generate java classes with the JAXB plugin. However, when using the following file, it only generates a `sun.jaxb.episode` file. No error is thrown but no classes are generated either.

pom.xml:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

wsdl-file:

```xml
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" name="IAWLSOAPservice" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
    <message name="ProcessName0Request">
        <part name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="OrgClient" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ProcessName0Response">
        <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ProcessNameExt1Request">
        <part name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="DOB" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="Nationality" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="Address" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="City" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="State" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="Zip" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="OrgClient" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ProcessNameExt1Response">
        <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetRecordStatus2Request">
        <part name="BusinessCaseID" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="OrgClient" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetRecordStatus2Response">
        <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetQueryStatus3Request">
        <part name="BusinessCaseID" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="OrgClient" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetQueryStatus3Response">
        <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetQueryResultsXML4Request">
        <part name="BusinessCaseID" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="OrgClient" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetQueryResultsXML4Response">
        <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetQueryResultsHTML5Request">
        <part name="BusinessCaseID" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="user" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="pwd" type="xs:string"/>
        <part name="OrgClient" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetQueryResultsHTML5Response">
        <part name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="IAWLSOAP">
        <operation name="ProcessName">
            <input message="tns:ProcessName0Request"/>
            <output message="tns:ProcessName0Response"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="ProcessNameExt">
            <input message="tns:ProcessNameExt1Request"/>
            <output message="tns:ProcessNameExt1Response"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetRecordStatus">
            <input message="tns:GetRecordStatus2Request"/>
            <output message="tns:GetRecordStatus2Response"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetQueryStatus">
            <input message="tns:GetQueryStatus3Request"/>
            <output message="tns:GetQueryStatus3Response"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetQueryResultsXML">
            <input message="tns:GetQueryResultsXML4Request"/>
            <output message="tns:GetQueryResultsXML4Response"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetQueryResultsHTML">
            <input message="tns:GetQueryResultsHTML5Request"/>
            <output message="tns:GetQueryResultsHTML5Response"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="IAWLSOAPbinding" type="tns:IAWLSOAP">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="ProcessName">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP#ProcessName" style="rpc"/>
            <input message="tns:ProcessName0Request">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </input>
            <output message="tns:ProcessName0Response">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="ProcessNameExt">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP#ProcessNameExt" style="rpc"/>
            <input message="tns:ProcessNameExt1Request">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </input>
            <output message="tns:ProcessNameExt1Response">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetRecordStatus">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP#GetRecordStatus" style="rpc"/>
            <input message="tns:GetRecordStatus2Request">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </input>
            <output message="tns:GetRecordStatus2Response">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetQueryStatus">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP#GetQueryStatus" style="rpc"/>
            <input message="tns:GetQueryStatus3Request">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </input>
            <output message="tns:GetQueryStatus3Response">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetQueryResultsXML">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP#GetQueryResultsXML" style="rpc"/>
            <input message="tns:GetQueryResultsXML4Request">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </input>
            <output message="tns:GetQueryResultsXML4Response">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetQueryResultsHTML">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP#GetQueryResultsHTML" style="rpc"/>
            <input message="tns:GetQueryResultsHTML5Request">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </input>
            <output message="tns:GetQueryResultsHTML5Response">
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:AWLSOAP-IAWLSOAP"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="IAWLSOAPservice">
        <port name="IAWLSOAPPort" binding="tns:IAWLSOAPbinding">
            <soap:address location="http://somedomain.com/Scripts/AMLWebServiceISAPI.dll/soap/IAWLSOAP"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

When using a [differently formatted wsdl file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Java-Techie-jt/spring-boot-soap-ws-consumer/master/src/main/resources/wsdl/loanEligibility.wsdl), it generates the classes fine. So the problem seems to be with JAXB in combination with my wsdl-file. Any ideas why it cannot generate any java classes?

Comment: There aren't any types in the wsdl. It only has message and ports. So all can be included in the Binding interfaces.

Comment: I have a similar issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Did u mange to fix it? I have the same issue